# marquee behavior:alternate

Tags: jquery, marquee, alternate

I search and try a lot to do marquee with property behavior : alternate with jQuery but I don't find any result which compatible  **with all browser**..
please Help me...
old marquee

```
<marquee behavior=alternate>MY TEXT</marquee>
```

what I try

```
<script>
```

but no result 
also I search that with a lot of result .. try them but no result .. please help

Comment: I've formatted your question to show your code, but you appear to have forgotten to include the actual script you tried.

Comment: many thanks for Mr.David Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Hi there is a plugin you can use:

http://plugins.jquery.com/marquee/

Its easy to use - see a demo here: 
http://aamirafridi.com/jquery/jquery-marquee-plugin#examples

Literally after the plugin is added its just `$('.selector').marquee();` 
To make it go left then right:

```
var vDirection = 'left';
    setInterval(function(){
        $('.marquee2').marquee({ duration: 5000,
        gap: 50,
        delayBeforeStart: 0,
        direction: vDirection,
        duplicated: true
    });
    vDirection = vDirection == 'left' ? 'right' : 'left';
    },700);
```

Adjust timing (700) to whatever you want.

Comment: I need it to bidirectional as I told behavior : alternate

Comment: @user3749615 scroll down in the demo link I gave you. it goes all directions.

Comment: I scrolled but the direction only right or left or up or down ... not ALTERNATE that goes left then right......

Comment: I tried what you wrote but my problem is the text don't move when even I use $('.selector').marquee(); only but text is static not move .... please would you please upload a simple project in asp.net so I can run it and see what is my fault ... thank you in advance and sorry for annoying

Comment: Please help me ... It is not work  with me .. I add scripts to script folder and called them in page then put codes in suitable place.. please help me ... because the text still don't move...

Comment: please help me  ................. even if there is a css method and compatible with different browsers tell me please

Answer (score 0):

Try this code which I learned from https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp and try more parameters from this web, there's no java code needed, only css.

```css
.noteex {
color: orange;
font-weight: bold;
font-style: italic;
font-size: 150%;
position: relative;
animation-name: notemarq;
animation-duration: 4s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-direction: alternate;
animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes notemarq {
0% {color: orange; left:0; top:0px;}
25%  {color: red;}
50%  {color: green;}
75%  {color: purple;}
100% {color: blue; left:60%; top:0px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="noteex">Good Note</div>
```